# Proof that regular constant-sized deposits always outgrow one-time deposit in the long run?

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, economics, geometric-series

I want to prove: Given a constant interest rate, no matter how small deposits $\beta$ as long as it goes regularly, we can always outgrow an arbitrarily large one-time lump-sum invested at the start of these constant deposits.
Here is my attempt at expressing it mathematically :

Assume $0<\beta<\alpha$ and $\xi >0$

$$\beta \sum_{k=0}^{k=N} (1+\xi)^k > \alpha  (1+\xi)^N $$

Can we prove we can always find sufficiently large $N_b$ so that the above is true $\forall N>N_b$ given the constraints on $\xi,\beta,\alpha$ ?

I am interested in both advanced solutions and simpler ones.

Comment: This seems false to me. Maybe I'm missing something.

Lets say a 1% interest rate. If you invest 200 at the start, and your steady deposits are 1 dollar. The Steady State case gains more in interest every period than your steady deposit.

After one period, we have 202$ vs. 1$, 204$ vs 1.01. The lump sum is accumulating more interest than the steady deposits can catch up to.

Comment: @TonyPeterson yep David already derived in his hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $0<\xi<1$, we have$$
\begin{align}&\beta \sum_{k=0}^{k=N} (1+\xi)^k > \alpha  (1+\xi)^N\iff\\
&\beta\frac{(1+\xi)^{N+1}-1}{\xi}>\alpha  (1+\xi)^N\iff\\
&\frac{\beta}{\alpha}>\frac{\xi(1+\xi)^N}{(1+\xi)^{N+1}-1}\iff\\
&\frac{\beta}{\alpha}>\frac{\xi}{1+\xi-(1+\xi)^{-N}}
\end{align}$$

The last expression goes to $\frac{\xi}{1+\xi}$ as $N\to\infty$ so provided $$\beta>\frac{\alpha\xi}{1+\xi}$$ the periodic deposits will accumulate to a larger amount over a sufficient period of time.

Comment: Even nicer! Great.

Answer (score 1):

HINT...the left hand side is a geometric series you can sum. Then rearrange the inequality. It looks like this only works if $$\beta>\alpha\xi$$
So $\beta$ cannot be arbitrarily small. But for suitable $\beta$ you can choose $N$ so that$$N>\frac{\log\beta-\log(\beta-\alpha\xi)}{\log(1+\xi)}$$

Comment: Nice one! Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: I got the condition $\beta>\frac{\alpha\xi}{1+\xi}$.

Comment: actually I agree @saulspatz my bad